# Why sending bitcoin and one addresss shows (Unspend) and one address shows (Spent)?

Tags: sendtoaddress

I sent some btc to a btc address, and each time I send btc, it splits into two addresses, only one of them is the real destination address. The recipient said he has not received the btc yet. I checked blockchain info, it shows the destination address (spent) but the other address as (unspent). This is normal, right? When the recipient's wallet address shows spent in the blochain explorer - does it mean that the btc has already appeared in his wallet?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

The second address your transaction sent to is called a ‘change address’. If you [search that term on this site](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/change) you can learn about what a change address is.

Here is a breakdown of the different status’ blockchain.info reports on their block explorer website:

- if it says ‘unconfirmed’, that means transaction is not yet confirmed (not yet included in a block)
- if it says ‘unspent’, that means the transaction went through, and the funds are still sitting in that address
- If it says ‘spent’, that means the transaction went through, and the recipient has already moved the funds to another new address

Comment: Thank you. But it's been shown (Unspent) for one address for more then 3 days. Why causes the fund to sit in that address and not move into the actual recipient wallet autmatically? Previous send to the same address went through fine, but the 2nd time sending to the same address, the fund just sits there, not automatically Spent. Please advise what recipient can do in this case.

Comment: @JakeJohnson if I understand correctly, your tx has two outputs: one to the recipient, and the other is your change address. Your wallet controls the change address. So if you have not sent a subsequent tx that spent the coins in the change address, then of course they would remain unspent. There is no ‘automatically spent’. If you re read my answer you will see that the ‘spent/unspent’ tag that blockchain.info reports has nothing to do with whether or not your tx has confirmed.

Comment: Do you have any solution to turn "Unspent" status of the change address into "Spent?" It was sent from a blockchain wallet, and their support said after so many confirmations, it's irreversible, they can't do anything to help either. It's up to the recipient. But the recipient doesn't know what to do to claim the fund sitting on the network. Sending from Blockchain was always fast, but this time, it's stuck. Blockchain Wallet Support said it's not sender's issue and there's nothing they can do to help. The recipient doesn't know what to do. Please advise. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Plz post the tx ID or address here so i can look. The unspent change address should be controlled by your blockchain.info wallet. To spend a utxo, the wallet that controls that address’ private keys needs to send a new tx using that utxo.

Comment: chytrik, thank you very much for offering help. Could you provide an email address, I'd be happy to send you the TXID to your email privately.

Comment: @JakeJohnson There is nothing to concern with posting a txid, it is already public information unless you do not want it to be associated with your user ID here.